# What is the meaning of 헛짚기?

Tags: translation

Here is the full sentence:
헛짚기도 이 정도면 예슬이다

And the translation is "even a straw is enough to make a false guess" but i can't find the particular meaning of 헛짚기

Answer (score 5):

헛- is a suffix for false, fake, or sometimes secondary quality.  (E.g., 헛소리 nonsense, 헛짓 meaningless action.)

The original meaning of 짚기 is to put your finger/hand on something, but here it is used metaphorically, as in putting your finger on a subject.  So, 헛짚기 basically means "missing the point", or "failing to get an (obvious) social cue."

이 정도면 예술이다 (Note: it's 예술, not 예슬) is a common expression meaning "it is good enough to be called an art", i.e., "it's really good," but it's frequently used sarcastically, as in here.

So the sentence means "[You are] missing the point by so much that it has attained a quality of art," or in a more colloquial English, "Dude, you're missing the point by a mile."

- Also, it's best not to use Google/Naver translate to learn Korean.

Answer (score 2):

`헛짚기` is a noun form of `헛짚다` or `헛다리짚다`.

It means `mistake` in English. Also it's an extremely informal, slang-ish vocabulary.

"헛짚기도 이 정도면 예술이다" is a common phrase for pointing out someone's mistake, and is a sarcasm.

Here's how Korean dictionary (표준국어대사전) explains `헛짚기`:

---

> [헛짚다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/small_detail.nhn?docid=42258800)
>
> 헛-짚다[발음 : 헏찝따]
>
> 활용 : 헛짚어, 헛짚으니, 헛짚는[헛짐는]
>
> ---
>
> 동사
>
> 「…을」
>
> 1 . **바닥을 바로 짚지 못하다.**
>
> - 익숙한 길인데 오늘따라 그는 지팡이를 자꾸 헛짚는다.
> - 소년은 달리기 시작했다. 디딤돌을 헛짚었다. 한 발이 물속에 빠졌다. (출처 : 황순원, 소나기)
> - 나는 무엇에 떠밀리듯 허겁지겁 기어가기 시작했다. 몇 발짝쯤 기었을까, 별안간 손을 헛짚으며 내 몸은 거꾸로 떨어져 곤두박질쳤다. (출처 : 유재용, 성역)
>
> 2 . **상황을 잘못 짐작하다.**
>
> 3 . **진맥 따위를 잘못 보다.**
>
> - 이럴 리가 없는 일이 분명하여 진 의원은, 잘못 헛짚은 것인가 하고 정신을 수습한 뒤 호흡을 정돈하고 침착하게 손가락을 모았다. (출처 : 최명희, 혼불)

---

> [헛다리짚다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/small_detail.nhn?docid=80370324)
>
> 1 . 「◀(명사)가▶」 **대상을 잘못 파악하여 일을 그르치다.**
>
> - 정말 그렇게 될 것이라고 생각했다면, 당신은 헛다리짚은 거예요.
>
> 2 . 「◀(명사)가▶」 **아무 성과 없이 끝나다.**

---

Answer (score 1):

헛 false 짚기 picking up

헛짚기 = 헛 다리(leg) 짚기

Usually, when there are a sequence of events, a success rate of our
choice is close to a half.

But unfortunately, someone picks wrong choice in almost events. In a
probability, it is equal to choose true in all events.

헛짚기도 이 정도면 예술이다.

=In light of these decisions, you have an artistic sense definitely in picking
up a false thing.

=In light of your choices, picking up a false thing is *also* one among artistic areas.